# Proving gcd(a+b,a-b) >= gcd(a,b)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $gcd(a+b, a-b)\geq gcd(a,b)$.

Right now am not seeing a way to approach this.

here are the relevant relationships in the book:

1)$lcm(a,b)=ab/gcd(a,b)$

2)$lcm(ab,ad)=a[lcm(b,d)]$

Comment: Hint:  Try showing that $gcd(a,b)$ divides $gcd(a+b,a-b)$

Comment: If something divides $a$ and $b$ then it divides $a+b$ and $a-b$.  Doesn't that prove it?

Comment: Ok I will consider the hints! Thanks, everyone!

Comment: $\gcd(a+b, a-b)=  \gcd(a,b)$ or $\gcd(a+b, a-b) = 2 \gcd(a,b)$, with the latter being true when the highest powers of $2$ dividing $a$ and $b$ are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[\gcd(a,b)|a]\wedge[\gcd(a,b)|b]\implies$

$[\gcd(a,b)|a+b]\wedge[\gcd(a,b)|b-a]\implies$

$[\gcd(a,b)\leq\gcd(a+b,a-b)]$

Comment: What is that, $\wedge$, symbol?

Comment: @VladimirLouis: Logical **AND**.

Comment: ok thanks! I will take a look at the proof. Thanks!

Comment: ok I understand. thanks!

Comment: @VladimirLouis: You're welcome :)

Comment: I am sorry I was under the impression one could accept multiple answers! I was just accepting others as well. I am new to the site. Am still learning the nuances.

Answer (score 1):

Let $gcd(a,b)=d$. Then $d|a$ and $d|b$. Therefore $d|a+b, d|a-b$ and hence $d|gcd(a+b,a-b)$ which implies that $d\leq gcd(a+b,a-b)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ d= \gcd(a,b)\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid a\!+\!b,a\!-\!b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid\gcd(a+b,a-b).\ $ Alternatively

---

$\qquad\ \  \gcd(a,b)\,$ is the least positive element of $\ S\, =\, a\,\Bbb Z + b\,\Bbb Z,\ $ by Bezout. Similarly

$\qquad\ \   \gcd(a\!+\!b,a\!-\!b)\,$ is the least positive element of $\ T\, =\, (a\!+\!b)\,\Bbb Z +(a\!-\!b)\,\Bbb Z$

But $\displaystyle \, S\supseteq T \ $  since $\ t\in T\,\Rightarrow\, t\, =\, m(a\!+\!b) + n(a\!-\!b)\, =\, (m\!+\!n) a + (m\!-\!n) b \in S.\ $

Therefore $S$'s least positive element is $\le$ $\,T$'s, $ $ i.e.  $\ \gcd(a,b)\, \le\, \gcd(a\!+\!b,a\!-\!b)$